# htaccess serve minimal 404 page to specific client ip (robots)

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, http-status-code-404

I have a drupal website which serves customized 404 pages (alternative content similar to that not found is searched and displayed in the 404 page), generating these pages is of course expensive in terms of resources so I'm currently wasting a lot of resources servig customized 404 pages to robots.
How can I setup my htaccess in order to serve a very light 404 page only to robots ip addresses? (without bootstraping drupal at all similarly to this example https://tedserbinski.com/drupal/preventing-drupal-from-handling-404s-for-performance/)
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you wanting to essentially block this bot? ie. _always_ serve a 404 to this bot, regardless of whether the requested URL exists or not, or only change the normal 404 response for this bot? If you want to block this bot (by IP) then this is relatively trivial to do in `.htaccess`. However, if you want to customise the 404 page then `.htaccess` is not the tool - since Drupal stores URLs in a DB, it's not possible to reliably know what is or is not a 404 until Drupal has performed DB lookups etc (which you can't do from `.htaccess`).

Comment: However, if you want to customise the 404 page then .htaccess is not the tool - since Drupal stores URLs in a DB, it's not possible to reliably know what is or is not a 404 until Drupal has performed DB lookups etc --- true, thank you for the reply.